# how to use AND and OR together in php

Tags: php

Am trying to write a simple PHP function that uses both && and || function in php but am only able to use the && function, i get a desired result as shown with the below code

```
<?php
$srt = "asc";
if($srt != "" && $srt != "asc"){
    echo "close";
    } else {
    echo "open";
    }
?>

output >> open
```

But when i add the || function to it i get the wrong result

```
<?php
$srt = "asc";
if($srt != "" && $srt != "asc" || $srt != "desc"){
    echo "close";
    } else {
    echo "open";
    }
?>

output >> close
```

I have also try using AND in place of **&&** and OR in place of **||** since php accepts both but i still get the same result am new to php so i dont know if what am trying is allowed or not so any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use parenthesis `if($srt != "" && ($srt != "asc" || $srt != "desc") ){`

Comment: `if ($srt != "" && ($srt != "asc" || $srt != "desc"))` use extra parenthesis to make it an expression

Comment: Or better `if (!in_array($srt, ['', 'asc', 'desc'])`.

Comment: The in_array works flawlessly thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use extra parenthesis to make it an expression.

```
if ($srt != "" && ($srt != "asc" || $srt != "desc"))
```

So you compare `$srt != ""` **AND** `$srt != "asc" || $srt != "desc"`.

Your code can be improved for readability as

```
if (!in_array($srt, ['', 'asc', 'desc']))
```